# js confirm vs php code

Tags: php, server-side, confirm

I'm currently writing a php script that is checking if there's no image in a array.
If there is no images, i need a messagebox (i use jquery msgbox) that ask if you wan't to create a product without an image.

If the user clicks yes, how do i then return true so the php code can be executed?
I know php is server side, so I "just" need your suggestion, what's the best solution here.

Currently my code is something like:

```
<?php if(!isset($_POST['img'] //imagearray)){?>

        <script>
            $.msgBox({
                title: "Sure?",
                content: "Add product without images?",
                type: "confirm",
                buttons: [{ value: "Yes" }, { value: "No" }, { value: "Cancel"}],
                success: function (result) {

                if (result == "Yes") {
                    return true;
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
        </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Why don't you just check on JS side if a image is set? Bind to the submit event of your form, and if no image is set, ask your user and then return true or false

Comment: could you post a code example? that would help a lot :)

Comment: Quick note, if you are posting images to your PHP script should you be using `$_FILES` rather than `$_POST` to deal with those images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here is an example,

```
<script>
$("#my-super-form").submit(function(event) {
  if($("#id-of-your-image-input").val()=="")
    if(confirm("Add product without image?")) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false
    }
  }
  return true;
});
</script>
```

Its not tested, but I think you can figure out how it works.

Comment: I'm currently testing your solution with some customization made.
But it seems like no matter what i'm trying, it dosent work. Could it be because the image field is an array?

Comment: Where do you store your images? Inside an array? Or is the user able to select images to upload? You have to check if the place is empty, where you store your images (go for length of array, or the string inside the upload textfield...)

Comment: The user selects the image and then they are stored in an array.
ex: type="file" name="img[]"

Comment: Then replace the ``if($("#id-of-your-image-input").val()=="")`` with your test if the array is empty

Comment: And how do i test if an array is empty when referring to an html input field? :-)

Comment: Updated with code that works for all file inputs and not just the first. http://jsbin.com/asizad/2/edit

Comment: Thank you very much. This leeds to a new question.
when i hit submit with a conf, the confirmation will load before the form has been validated. How do i prevent this?

Comment: I did it by using:
jQuery("#formID").validationEngine('attach', {
    onValidationComplete: function(form, status){
    if (status == true) {
})
:)

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery, you want to check if image is set after the post.

When user click is sent button, you can use your confirm messageBox, if image not found ^^

it's more intuitive for user.

Comment: but the problem for me still seems that i don't know the right way to execute the php code when something has returned false

Comment: but, 23tux has also solution ;) : First, when user click in post, you check if image exist, for advertise user, if user click in the confirm, you just post your form, if user want to add image, you just hide confirm message box :p